# Qual è il significato di "mamozio" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Alla fine lei stessa, come se in quello spazio fosse sola, cercò di sollevare il telaio, ma non ce la fece. Intervenne prontamente Marcello, intervenni io, lo appoggiammo alla parete. Poi tutti arretrammo verso la soglia, chi ridacchiando, chi torvo, chi esterrefatto. Il corpo in immagine di Lila sposa appariva crudelmente trinciato. Gran parte della testa era scomparsa, così la pancia. Restava un occhio, la mano su cui poggiava il mento, la macchia splendente della bocca, strisce in diagonale del busto, la linea delle gambe accavallate, le scarpe. 
>         Cominciò Gigliola, contenendo a stento la rabbia: 
>         «Io non ci posso mettere una cosa così nel *mio* negozio». 
>         «Sono d’accordo» esplose Pinuccia, «qua dobbiamo vendere e invece con questo **mamozio** la gente se ne scappa. Rino, di’ qualcosa a tua sorella, per favore».

Ho trovato questa [entrata di Wikipedia sul termine "Mamozio"](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamozio), ma non mi è stata utile per capire il senso che ha questo vocabolo nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tratta di un termine dialettale napoletano il cui senso nel brano è: una figura sgraziata, non presentabile riferito alla figura della sposa, che appare compromessa (con parte della figura mancante).

> - ***Spesso si definisce “[mamozio](http://www.vesuviolive.it/cultura-napoletana/proverbi-napoletani/104113-sie-nu-mamozio-cosa-significa-e-da-dove-deriva-questo-modo-di-dire/)” una persona credulona, buffa, stolta e un po’ strana: ma da dove deriva questo modo di dire?*** Il tutto ha avuto inizio in un lontano giorno del 1704 quando a Pozzuoli durante gli scavi per la costruzione della chiesa di San Giuseppe venne ritrovata una statua senza testa ***appartenente al console romano Quinto Flavio Mesio Egnazio Lolliano Mavorzio***.
>
> [image]
>
> - ***Alla scultura venne integrata una nuova testa che però risultò essere sproporzionata e molto più piccola del corpo. Il risultato causò un’armonia inesistente che dava a Lolliano Mavorzio un’aria poco credibile e molto comica. Il nome del console venne poi storpiato dagli abitanti di Pozzuoli che iniziarono a chiamare la statua “Mamozio”***, termine che si è consolidato nel tempo assumendo il significato di persona tonta, stupida e dall’aria imbambolata.